# Mysql connector Python Syntax error

Tags: python, mysql, database, connector

I want to run the create function in a tkinter interface but it give me this error:

> 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near ''' (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,cash INT,dt DATE, PRIMARY
>   KEY(id))' at line 1

This is the code. I have tried a lot of thinks but nothing...

```
    from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection, Error
    from tkinter import *

    DB_HOST = 'localhost'
    DB_USER = 'root'
    DB_PASS = 'mysql123'
    DB_NAME = 'Savings'

    def create(Name):
        try:
            connection = MySQLConnection(host=DB_HOST,user=DB_USER,password=DB_PASS,database=DB_NAME)
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            tabla = Name.get()
            cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE %s (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,cash INT,dt DATE, PRIMARY KEY(id))", (tabla,))
            print("Hecho!")
        except Error as e:
            print(e)
        finally:
            connection.commit()
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
```

Comment: i am no python to sql guy, but what is with the trailing comma in last chunk for replacement ? `(tabla,)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *cannot parameterize table or column names*. Use string formatting (but make sure you trust your source or validate the input table name carefully):

```
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE {table} (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,cash INT,dt DATE, PRIMARY KEY(id))".format(table=tabla))
```

---

Note that you can use the mysql connector to escape strings:

```
tabla = connection.converter.escape(tabla)
```

Comment: Thanks you! I didn't know that It can't parameterize tables.